# sysctl: permission denied on key "fs.inotify.max_user_instances"

Tags: systemctl, inotify

I'm running a docker container, in the development environment. I'm trying to set the `fs.inotify.max_user_instances` value.

Since inside the docker container I'm the root user, thus the `sudo` is not needed. In fact, if I run `sudo command_text` I get:

> bash: sudo: command not found

Thus I run `sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192` to increase the `max_user_instances` value. To my surprise I get this error:

> sysctl: permission denied on key "fs.inotify.max_user_instances"

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068172/1269127) I realized that even the root user could not change some stuff because they affect the entire machine (though this seems silly because the root user is the owner of the system in some sense and should be able to change the whole machine if he wanted to).

Using `-w` flag makes not difference. Still the same error.

Thus I tried `echo 8192 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances` to directly override the value inside the related file. And I got:

> bash: /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances: Read-only file system

I did not try to change the file system permissions. Because at this point I felt that this is probably not a good idea.

How can I safely increase the `inotify` quota inside a Docker container, as the root user?

**Update**

I even tried `chmod +w max_user_instances`, and I got this error:

> chmod: changing permissions of 'max_user_instances': Read-only file system

My OS is:

```
root@panel:/# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: in simple words, docker is a extended chroot manager. Means, the kernel and all related things are used from the "parent". Changing these things would lead to changes in the parent, which is of course not allowed. You need a "real" virtual machine to manipulate such things (e.g. virtualbox).

Comment: @Marco, is there a way to configure docker to change these settings? I mean indirectly?

Comment: @Marco, also does this mean that if I change the `max_user_instances` on my Ubuntu machine (the host) then it would be changed in all of the containers that run inside it?

Comment: Yes, this is how docker/chroot works.

Comment: @Marco, you're right. I did that on my host machine, and it immediately worked for the container. Can you please send your comment with more explanations as an answer so that I would accept it for future references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words, Docker uses the technique of `chroot` with an overlay file-system to run a container.

The running container uses the host kernel and it's kernel parameters (sysctl).

Pseudo file-systems (`/proc`, `/sys`, ...) are mounted from the host read-only.

Changes on kernel parameters on the host are immediately seen in the running docker container. From the docker container, you can not change the kernel parameter of the host (read-only).

There are many details with Docker, which I do not mention for simplicity and response to the question. See Docker manual for all the details.